# difference between $cookiestore and $cookies in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

What is the difference between `$cookiestore` and `$cookies` in angularjs.

I saw the `angularjs` document.

$cookiestore and $cookies are doing  same think, but the only difference is

> **$cookiestore**- can objects put or retrieved from this storage are automatically *serialized* or *deserialized* by angular's *toJson/fromJson* .but
>   **$cookies**- can't  do this

Is the only one difference? or anything else?

Comment: I would look into this more, but the docs say: "Deprecated: (since v1.4.0)
Please use the $cookies service instead." so it seems kind of moot.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the description of each in the documentation makes it quite clear:

> $cookie just gives you access to cookies same as if you did by some
>   other method.
>
> $cookieStore uses cookies to make a key/value storage solution for
>   you.

So if you are starting something new and want to persist key/value pairs use $cookieStore

If you want to use existing cookie solution - say read/write cookies from your existing server session system then use $cookie.